# "Cannot read property 'options' of undefined" EasyUI when trying to update datagrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, local-storage, jquery-easyui

On page load, I want to load JSON from the local storage to be able to update an interactive "shopping cart". When the user quits the page and comes back, I want the items to still be there.

At the end of my operation of the interactive shopping cart, I save the data to the local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("datastr", JSON.stringify(data));
```

This works fine, because when I load the page, I check if there's data in the local storage and log its details.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("datastr") !== null) {
    console.log("data found");
```

I then add the items to an array:

```
data.rows.push({
            name:loadedarray.name,
            quantity:loadedarray.quantity,
            price:loadedarray.price
        });
```

But when I try to update the datagrid with the items,

```
$('#cartcontent').datagrid('loadData',loadedarray);
```

It gives me the following error:

```
"Cannot read property 'options' of undefined"
```

I assume this error means that it's trying to read something that doesn't exist, but I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

[Here's the full JS file](http://pastebin.com/55j1Apw9) if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working test I built with the data you have provided. Hopefully you can find your issue by comparing your code to mine.

```
function setLocalStorage() {
  var data = [];
  data.push({name: "foo", quantity: 10, price: 4.99});
  data.push({name: "bar", quantity: 4, price: 9.99});
  localStorage.setItem("datastr", JSON.stringify(data));
}

function getLocalStorage() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("datastr") !== null) {
    var loadedarray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("datastr"));
    var data = [];
    data.rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < loadedarray.length; i++) {
      var curr = loadedarray[i];
      data.rows.push({
        name: curr.name,
        quantity: curr.quantity,
        price: curr.price
      });
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < data.rows.length; j++) {
      var curr = data.rows[j];
      console.log("row " + j + ": " + curr.name + " " + curr.quantity + " $" + curr.price);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed a bit when I wrote the question yesterday.  
    `$('#cartcontent').datagrid('loadData',loadedarray);`  
is the line that's giving me issues. datagrid is a function from JQuery EasyUI. I'm not sure if  you know anything about it.

Comment: I also added the whole JS code to the OP in the pastebin

Comment: I think it might be the order of operations that is giving you grief. Try moving this method "if (localStorage.getItem("datastr") !== null) {" and its contents to after you initialize the datagrid. "$('#cartcontent').datagrid({
singleSelect:true });"

Comment: @davidpox Any luck with reordering the methods?

Comment: I had a talk with my tutor and he manage to fix it. Point No 1, I $(function() {}); and $(document).ready(function({}); are the same function, so he fused those together. And also, he stored the parsed JSON in the data array